# FactoryGirl with RSpec

Tags: rspec, factory-bot, factories

I am writing an RSpec using `FactoryGirl`. It has been giving errors

```
   NoMethodError: undefined method `saved?' for nil:NilClass
```

I think this error is happening because the object C is not being initialized properly. Here I have defined three models A, B and C among which model C is dependent on other two models. I have written them in factory.rb in no particular order i.e. first I have written C then A and B. I would like to know whether they have to be defined in particular order according to the dependency. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order of definition does not matter in `FactoryGirl` definitions in terms of any code that is within the blocks being passed in. That's because the code within the blocks is not executed until the factories are actually invoked.